# Change the router path

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to change the router when a function is called:

```js
register() {
  if (this.password === this.confirmPass) {
    this.submit = true
    this.active = true
    this.errorMessage = ''
    this.$emit('user-added', userName)
    ;('some code here to change the route')
  } else {
    this.errorMessage = 'password does not match!'
  }
}
```

Comment: please give more details. What's going on? What's your expected result?

Comment: what do you mean by change the router? like `router.push` ?

Comment: I'm in register.vue component and I'm wanna  come back to home.vue component if password and confirm password are the same,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using vue-router, you can change the route like this `this.$router.push('/some-route')` or use the name of your route `this.$router.push({ name: 'nameOfRoute' })`

Comment: yes I'm using vue-router, it dosen't work for me. is this for using in a function?

Comment: this is where my function trigger...
<v-btn
        :disabled="!valid"
        color="#152437"
        class="mr-4"
        @click="register()"
      >
      Register
      </v-btn>

Comment: Yes, this is used in a function/method. If `this.$router.push('/some-route')` doesn't work, you should check if your vue-router is initiated correctly. Can you show us how you initialize your router?

Comment: this is my router.js file
import Home from "./components/Home.vue";
import Register from "./components/router/Register.vue";
import SignIn from "./components/router/SignIn.vue";

export const routes = [
  { path: "", component: Home },
  { path: "/register", component: Register },
  { path: "/sign-in", component: SignIn }

Answer (score 0):

you can use `router.push('home')`to change the switch between routes.